# Percentages in the wrong position in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, percentage

I'm trying to plot a graph for a likert test using ggplot2 and I would like to have the percentages values appearing on the graph. I've created a df with all the averages and percentages so I could write it on the graph. It all seems to be working good, except the values are being plotted as if they were upsided or something.

This is the code I'm using

```
    example <- structure(list(grupo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("EJA", 
"REG"), class = "factor"), nivel = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("CINCO", "DOZE", "NOVE"), class = "factor"), tipo = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("COR", "PAD", "RES"), class = "factor"), 
    likert = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1", "2", "3"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), cnt = c(3L, 
    1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 
    6L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 10L), freq = c(0.25, 0.083, 0.25, 0.417, 
    0.231, 0.077, 0.231, 0.462, 0.154, 0.077, 0.769, 0.167, 0.167, 
    0.3, 0.367, 0.2, 0.133, 0.333, 0.333, 0.333), prop = c(25, 
    8.3, 25, 41.7, 23.1, 7.7, 23.1, 46.2, 15.4, 7.7, 76.9, 16.7, 
    16.7, 30, 36.7, 20, 13.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3), proptext = c("25", 
    "8.3", "25", "41.7", "23.1", "7.7", "23.1", "46.2", "15.4", 
    "7.7", "76.9", "16.7", "16.7", "30", "36.7", "20", "13.3", 
    "33.3", "33.3", "33.3")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    grupo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("EJA", 
    "REG"), class = "factor"), nivel = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CINCO", "DOZE", "NOVE"), class = "factor"), 
    tipo = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("COR", 
    "PAD", "RES"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:4, 5:8, 9:11, 12:15, 16:19, 20L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
    
    ggplot(example, aes(x=(interaction(grupo, nivel, tipo)),y=prop, fill=likert))+
      geom_col()+
      #scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+
      coord_flip() +
      ggtitle("Testing")+
      xlab("A, B, and C")+
      ylab("%")+
      geom_text(aes(label = proptext), size = 2, colour = "black")
```

Would someone have an idea of how could I solve it?

Comment: @akrun is it a problem? is there something I can do to solve it?

Comment: I think that is not the only issue by looking at your code

Comment: I changed it now so the proptext was not a list column anymore (it became a list column because I was trying to add the % symbol so it could also appear on the graph). I ran it again but the problem remained, the numbers on the graph are not at the right places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `geom_text` may also require the `x`, `y`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
example %>%    
  unite(new, grupo, nivel, tipo, sep = ".") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=new, fill=likert))+
    geom_col(aes(y= prop))+
    geom_text(aes(x = new, y = prop, label = proptext),
     position = position_stack(vjust = .5)) + 
  coord_flip() +
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+
  
  ggtitle("Testing")+
  xlab("A, B, and C")+
  ylab("%")
```

-output

[image]